# Unable to set the y of the font to 1 in the windows console

Tags: c, api, windows-10

I recently experienced some a.p.i. of the windows console in C, and, in particular, those for managing the buffer and the window.
My goal is to treat the prompt as a window for graphics where pixels are represented by characters.
To have a good resolution, and to be able to approximate the pixel to a character, I need to minimize the font size.
An example I tried on my machine is 400 * 400 characters of size 1 * 1.
On my computer (W10) I use the console api and I don't have any kind of problem, in fact I can create the aforementioned window.
The problem arises when I start the executable on other PCs.
Proceeding by trial and error, I came to the conclusion that the malfunction occurs only if the y dimension of the font is 1.
For example, trying to create a 400 * 400 window of 1 * 1 characters, each character will actually have a size of 1 * 3 (in fact this leads to a rectangular window).
Any other size works perfectly (2 * 2.1 * 2.3 * 3.1 * 5, ...).
Furthermore, the a.p.i. they do not return any type of error.
This is the code I am using:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    int Ydim = 400; int Xdim = 400;
    int PY = 1; int PX = 1;

    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);

        //  Minimize the window as the buffer may become smaller than the current size 
        //  (but it could never become smaller than 0,0,1,1)
    SMALL_RECT h = {0,0,1,1};
    if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &h))
        return -1;

    
        // Change font dimensions
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfx;
    cfx.cbSize = sizeof(cfx);
    cfx.dwFontSize.X = PX;
    cfx.dwFontSize.Y = PY;
    cfx.nFont = 0;
    cfx.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfx.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    wcscpy(cfx.FaceName, L"Consolas");

    if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, FALSE, &cfx))
        return -1;
        
    
    COORD a = {Xdim,Ydim};
    if (!SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hConsole,a))
        return -1;
    

        //  The physical window has the same dimension of the font
    SMALL_RECT k = {0,0,a.X - 1,a.Y - 1};
    if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &k))
        return -1;


    Sleep(30000);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the screenshots (this is the same program)

[In my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AajFN.png)

[On other machines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCiEA.png)

You can see that i have highlited a character on each image to prove that they are different.
I would like to specify that I am using the same version of windows on every machine.
I hope I have explained the problem well enough. Any help in trying to solve it is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no suggestions other than to check the Windows Console version between the different machines. The problem is that your goal is to use the terminal in a way that it is not designed, and struggling because it fails. Why not just open a GDI window like all other Windows applications? It is designed to work and does so very well, and affords full color. (You are talking to someone who has done this kind of thing, but never at such a high resolution, because it doesn’t play nice for the reason already given. BTW, you should be treating each character cell as _two_ pixels: top and bottom.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas I checked every customization from the two GUIs of the prompt and they look the same. You are right anyway. I was wrong not specifying that this isnt the way someone should use the console. Im doing this just for fun and because i wanted to create a really basic library for graphics in the prompt. Anyway thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Lol, that’s fine. Like I said, I’ve done the same thing myself. (Many, many... er, maybe too many times.) Playing with text graphics is fun! Don’t give it up, just remember that it is a different medium than a graphical bitmap image window.

Comment: Also, for bitmap graphics in the window, remember that a character cell is typically rectangular. Using the ▄ or ▀ characters gets you two “pixels” per character cell: set your foreground and background colors appropriately. The hardest part is setting up the terminal with the proper font — which really requires the generation of a custom Shortcut (.lnk) file on your user’s PC to initialize it.

Comment: Sorry, last comment. There do exist several special-purpose fonts specifically for this kind of thing, but IDR where to find them. If you are interested I’m pretty sure a little Google-Fu will find them (and the ASCII-graphics forums/pages they are attached to).

Comment: @Dúthomhas Thanks for your advices! I've never thought about treating each character  cell as two pixel!, this could also make it possible to use a 1*1 resolution. Thanks also for the graphics fonts ideas.